# How to add eg Admin in front of name?

Tags: cmd

Hellow I want to ad eg admin in front of specific name.

```
@echo off

echo Enter ID 

set /p input=""

cls

echo Welocme  %input%

pause
```

In this script i want to add if i write eg Modman I want to in front of it be admin but if I write eg Bartek it wont be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaly something like:

```
@echo off
echo Enter ID
set /p input=""
cls
if %input% == "Modman" then set input="admin Modman"
echo Welcome %input%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple test to see if the input is `Modman` and add `Admin` if it is.

```
@echo off
echo Enter ID
set /p input=""
IF /I "%input%" EQU "Modman" (SET "input=Admin %input%")
cls
echo Welcome  %input%
pause
```

Comment: Thx and here should be space IF /I "%input%" EQU "Modman" (SET "input=Admin (the space)%input%")

Comment: Done. Done. Done.